# Java: Scrollbar doesn't appear, even though `setVerticalScrollBarPolicy` and other options are set

Tags: java, swing, awt, windowbuilder

I got an issue with my `JScrollpane`. I am adding Labels to it, out from a list. The adding is working and I see the labels. The amount of Labels added is unknown to me, so it can appear that the border of the `scrollpane` wont be enough. Thats the advantage of using a Scrollpane, so that I can actually scroll down if needed. But the scrollbar doesnt appear. I know there are many questions like that asked, but I tried almost every proposed suggestion. I tried `setPreferredSize()`, `setLayout()`, `scrollPaneApps.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS)`, but nothing of it worked.

```
public DisplayProperties() {

   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
   setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
   contentPane = new JPanel();
   setContentPane(contentPane);
   contentPane.setLayout(null);
   contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,300));

   JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
   scrollPane1.setBounds(15, 54, 195, 202);
   scrollPane1.setViewportBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
   scrollPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(185,195));
   scrollPane1.setLayout(null);   
   scrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
   contentPane.add(scrollPane1);


    int b = 0;

    for(String s : XMLParser.ApplicationsListGUI)
    {
        b = b + 20;
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("lbl"+s);
        lbl.setText(s);
        lbl.setBounds(10,b,100,15);
        scrollPane1.add(lbl);
        scrollPane1.revalidate();   
        lbl.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

So why doesnt this Scrollbar dont appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have two JScrollPanes involved, scrollPaneApps, which you set a vertical scrollbar policy, which you try to add a component to, but which you **never** add to the GUI, and scrollPane1, which you don't set a policy, never add components to, but **do** add to the GUI. Sorry, but this is totally crazy. You need to fix this so that your code makes sense:

- Add the actual JScrollPane that has its vertical scrollbar policy set to the GUI. If it's not added to the GUI, it makes sense that it will never be seen.
- Don't add components directly to the JScrollPane but rather to its JViewport via the `setViewportView(...)` method. Or you can add a component to the JScrollPane constructor which is little more than syntactic sugar for adding it to the viewport.
- Avoid null layouts and absolute positioning (avoid `setBounds(...)`). Using these will make your GUI's rigid, ugly, and almost impossible to improve upon later. **Never** set a JScrollPane's layout as null, for if you do, it will stop working. Completely.

Comment: Thanks for your input, my mistake posting the question, I have just one scrollpane, namely `scrollpane1`. Copy&Paste mistake while posting the question. I thought setting the null, uses its default layout.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't show since you have no layout for the `scrollPaneApps` panel. So **remove** this line and it should show.

```
scrollPane1.setLayout(null);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I didn't recommend it. I said to **remove** that line.